# Does Spanish have an equivalent of the pronoun "one"?

Tags: pronombres, oraciones-impersonales

In English, one can use the gender-neutral indefinite pronoun ["one"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_(pronoun)), e.g.:

> One does not simply walk into Mordor...

In most dialects of modern English, this is rarely used, being replaced by the impersonal "you".

Does a Spanish equivalent of the pronoun "one" exist? As in German *man/einer*, French *on*, Catalan *hom* etc. Or is the only option to use the [impersonal *se*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/12555/use-of-t%C3%BA-when-giving-examples/16438)?

Comment: Well, in this specific case we use _uno_: _Uno no va directamente..._. You can also head _uno tiene cierta edad ya_ when someone talks about themselves.

Comment: One=Uno. As simple as that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though it is indeed more common to use the impersonal *se* in analogues of such phrases:

> No se entra así como así en Mordor...

Spanish [does](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/24503/how-would-i-translate-the-following-into-spanish-that-seem-the-require-an-impers) have such a (subject) pronoun:

> [**uno<sup>2</sup>, na**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=b6iKApr)
> ...
> **11.** `pron. indef. m. sing.` Designa a una persona indeterminada.
>
> > *Uno debería saber cómo comportarse en esos casos.*

Comment: Another translation would be "Uno no entra así como así a Mordor"